# android - cancel runnable that already start running

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handlerthread

I have a long process in the background to do. So `onCreate`, I post a runnable in my handler from `handlerThread` but I have a button that allows users to cancel it. It's possible to stop a `Runnable` after it starts?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Handler h = new Handler( HandlerThread.getLooper() );
    Runnable runnable = //class that implements runnable;

    h.post( runnable );

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            h.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems that doesn't cancel runnable that already running, Or should I use `postDelayed()` with a huge delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your runnable have a boolean flag for `running`.

Your button then can set this flag to true/false, to stop it running.

You can implement pause, resume, or start, stop, it all depends on your usecase.

i.e. something like

```
while(running) {
   // Your repeated background code
}
```

or

```
if(running) {
   // do some one shot code, i.e. the user can stop it if they press the button before the if, but not after. 
}
```

You could also have multiple steps, allowing you to cancel mid way.

```
if(running) {
  // do step 1 code
}
if(running) {
  // do step 2 code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Comment: this cancels all the runnings, so that might cancel running that I want to keep running